# How to identify jump relationships in a neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Considering a graph like this:

```
A --> B --> C
A --> C
```

I would like to identify "jumping" relationships (in this case A to C) in order to keep only the longest path.

This is what I did so far:

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(d) 
MATCH p=(s)-[*0..]->(d) 
WHERE NOT r in relationships(p) 
SET r.ignore = true
```

I would like to know if it is the way to go, and if it is the most efficient ?

Now let suppose we remove the B --> C relationship, then the A --> C should not be ignored.

What could be a way to identify it and restore ?

Thanks a lot

Rémi

Comment: Are `s` and `d` a specific pair of nodes, or do you want to do this for every possible pair of nodes? If the latter, then what you want to do is not generally possible, since the same relationship could belong to the longest path between one pair of nodes and a non-longest path between a different pair.

Comment: I would like to do it for every possible pair of nodes. Could you please give an example of what you said, since I cannot see it the same way. I least in my graph structure I don't think it is possible. Thanks

Comment: Suppose, in addition to your top graph, there is also a `B-->D-->C` path. Then `B-->C` should be ignored (since it is the shorter path from `B` to `C`). But it should also not be ignored with respect to the path from `A` to `C`. You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: OK I see. In this case I want B-->C to be ignored as well since I want here to consider only the longest path which is A-->B-->D-->C. So for me that is correct to ignore B-->C. COnsidering only the longest paths, from B-->C it will be now B-->D-->C. Then my question remains the same, is my solution working and could I restore (in the case we delete B-->D later) ?

Comment: What should happen when there is a loop? Also, I don't think your query works because a variable-length relationship pattern can match partial paths (ie, when `d` is not a leaf node).

Comment: We have no loops, we are taking care of that. `d` is almost never a leaf, but I do not see where  is the problem in this case. I will continue to work on this but for now I did not find any counter example where this fail. Thanks a ton for your help !